# mdframed + amsthm + marginnote hides itemize bullet

Tags: itemize, mdframed, amsthm, marginnote

When using a marginnote inside a amsthm theorem inside an mdframed environment, the first itemize has its bullet destroyed:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newmdenv{definitionbox}
\declaretheorem{definitioninner}

\begin{document}
\begin{definitionbox}\definitioninner\marginnote{ABC}
blah
        \begin{itemize}
            \item test
            \item test
        \end{itemize}
\enddefinitioninner\end{definitionbox}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

If either of the components (the frame, the theorem or the note) is left out, the itemize works as normal.

Why does that happen and how do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason for not writing `blah\marginnote{ABC}`?

Comment: This is actually part of a set of defines that makes the margin note contain the name of the defines, I just stripped out that part to make the example shorter.

Comment: Add `leavevmode` before `\marginnote`. Do you have any reason to not use the `mfframed` key  with `\declaretheorem`? It would simplify the code.

Comment: @Bernard that works, thank you. As for your question, I was simply not aware of that key. My actual definition is fairly involved, so I don't know if it would simplify that much, but I might try.

Comment: I've tested , and you simply wouldn't have to nest the theorem in an mdframed environment – thmtools does it for you behind the scenes.

Comment: That does sound helpful, I will do that. If you post the leavevmode fix as a proper answer, I'll accept it btw